# Why does the argument for the find closure need two ampersands?

Tags: reference, rust

I have been playing with Rust by [porting my Score4 AI engine](https://github.com/ttsiodras/Score4/tree/master/Rust) to it - basing the work on my functional-style implementation in OCaml. I specifically wanted to see how Rust fares with functional-style code.

The end result: It works, and it's very fast - much faster than OCaml. It almost touches the speed of imperative-style C/C++ - which is really cool.

There's a thing that troubles me, though — why do I need two ampersands in the last line of this code?

```
let moves_and_scores: Vec<_> = moves_and_boards
    .iter()
    .map(|&(column,board)| (column, score_board(&board)))
    .collect();
let target_score = if maximize_or_minimize { 
    ORANGE_WINS 
} else { 
    YELLOW_WINS 
};
if let Some(killer_move) = moves_and_scores.iter()
    .find(|& &(_,score)| score==target_score) {
         ...
```

I added them is because the compiler errors "guided" me to it; but I am trying to understand why... I used the trick mentioned elsewhere in Stack Overflow to "ask" the compiler to tell me what type something is:

```
let moves_and_scores: Vec<_> = moves_and_boards
    .iter()
    .map(|&(column,board)| (column, score_board(&board)))
    .collect();
let () = moves_and_scores;
```

...which caused this error:

```
src/main.rs:108:9: 108:11 error: mismatched types:
 expected `collections::vec::Vec<(u32, i32)>`,
    found `()`
(expected struct `collections::vec::Vec`,
    found ()) [E0308]
src/main.rs:108     let () = moves_and_scores;
```

...as I expected, `moves_and_scores` is a vector of tuples: `Vec<(u32, i32)>`. But then, in the immediate next line, `iter()` and `find()` force me to use the hideous double ampersands in the closure parameter:

```
if let Some(killer_move) = moves_and_scores.iter()
    .find(|& &(_,score)| score==target_score) {
```

Why does the `find` closure need two ampersands? I could see why it may need one (pass the tuple by reference to save time/space) but why two? Is it because of the `iter`?  That is, is the `iter` creating references, and then `find` expects a reference on each input, so a reference on a reference?

If this is so, isn't this, arguably, a rather ugly design flaw in Rust?

In fact, I would expect `find` and `map` and all the rest of the functional primitives to be parts of the collections themselves. Forcing me to `iter()` to do any kind of functional-style work seems burdensome, and even more so if it forces this kind of "double ampersands" in every possible functional chain.

I am hoping I am missing something obvious - any help/clarification most welcome.

Comment: Congratulations on managing the port, beating OCaml on functional style code mean that you did something right!

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks! I was hoping there's a cleaner way to handle the functional chains  (i.e. `.iter().map(...).iter().filter() ... .iter().find(...)`) without introducing an extra level of reference at every step - but it seems I can't avoid it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This here

```
moves_and_scores.iter()
```

gives you an iterator over *borrowed* vector elements. If you follow the API doc what type this is, you'll notice that it's just the iterator for a borrowed slice and this implements `Iterator` with `Item=&T` where `T` is `(u32, i32)` in your case.

Then, you use `find` which takes a predicate which takes a `&Item` as parameter. Sice `Item` already is a reference in your case, the predicate has to take a `&&(u32, i32)`.

```
pub trait Iterator {
    ...
    fn find<P>(&mut self, predicate: P) -> Option<Self::Item>
    where P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool {...}
    ...            ^
```

It was probably defined like [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) because it's only supposed to inspect the item and return a bool. This does not require the item being passed by value.

If you want an iterator over `(u32, i32)` you could write

```
moves_and_scores.iter().cloned()
```

`cloned()` converts the iterator from one with an `Item` type `&T` to one with an `Item` type `T` if `T` is `Clone`. Another way to do it would be to use `into_iter()` instead of `iter()`.

```
moves_and_scores.into_iter()
```

The difference between the two is that the first option clones the borrowed elements while the 2nd one consumes the vector and moves the elements out of it.

By writing the lambda like this

```
|&&(_, score)| score == target_score
```

you destructure the "double reference" and create a local copy of the `i32`. This is allowed since `i32` is a simple type that is `Copy`.

Instead of destructuring the parameter of your predicate you could also write

```
|move_and_score| move_and_score.1 == target_score
```

because the dot operator automatically dereferences as many times as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Does `iter().cloned()` have a performance impact? I mean, does it actually allocate "clones"? Also, I believe `into_iter()` will definitely have a performance impact, since it's moving semantics will mutate the source vector.  I think the best is your third suggestion - using the "automatic dereference as many times as needed" - must read up on that.

Comment: BTW, any thoughts on why Rust chose not to have the functional operators (map, filter, etc) as part of the collections, and needs the `.iter()` first (which introduces an extra level of "reference-indirection" at each step)....?

Comment: @ttsiodras As for performance: None of it should really matter. Cloning a tuple of type `(u32, i32)` is very cheap. Don't let the word "clone" scare you. :-) For simpe "plain old data types" cloning and copying are basically the same. But some types cannot be copied because they are more complicated. Only in those cases, I would worry about cloning.

Comment: @ttsiodras There are many different kinds of ways you could iterate over a collection (`iter`, `iter_mut`, `into_iter`, `drain`). Each have their uses and there isn't really a "right" way to do this. I guess, that's why you have to be specific.

Comment: Rust is an amazing experience on software engineering